# Outputing HTML Ipython object to disk

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

How can I output an IPython HTML object of the form `<IPython.core.display.HTML object>` to a HTML file or PDF file on disk?

Answer (score 11):

You can do something like this:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML

a = HTML('<a href="http://example.com">LINK TO THE WEB PAGE</a>')
html = a.data
with open('html_file.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Comment: Could you explain in a more detailed way how can the solution be used?